# SQL get count of next 60 days of transactions after registration

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have every users registration date in a column. But I need to take that registration date and find every transaction made within 60 days after that and count them. I also need to do this all in one query. I am new to sql so am not sure if I should make temporary table or use a sub query to take that registration value and find the next 60 days worth of values.

So ideally this is what I would like returned

```
User_id  -----  registration_date -----   transactions
-------------------------------------------------
 - 4             1/1/2019                 43
 - 7             4/3/2017                 22
 - 9             3/3/2016                 15
```

Comment: "all in one query" and "make temporary table" don't match. So does this REALLY require a single (e.g., select) statement? But start simple. Select from the table that contains your user / registration. Use dateadd to add 60 days to the registration date. When you get that working, you can add the transaction logic.

Comment: Okay great thanks. So I used date add and now have a column of the user id, registration date, and date that is 60 days later. Now just wondering how I can take those dates and get a count?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide any DBMS, so I'll make a general answer.

**Problem** =
How do I get the transactions 60 days from a given date?

**Solution:**

In most database managing systems there are functions to convert a given date or timestamp to days. This means that we can use this function to calculate how many days are between 2 values. The following query will get you the result you are looking for (sort of):

```
SELECT 
User_id, 
registration_date, 
COUNT(transactions) as transactions FROM [db].[transactions]
WHERE TO_DAYS([db].[transactions]) - TO_DAYS([db].[transactions].[transaction_date]) <= 60
group by User_id, registration_date, transactions
```

However, in the query above, I'm not sure how to group them together. But the solution might be correct in your case.

Comment: The OP use the SQL Server tag from the first. That isn't a T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT JOIN` will get that information. For example:

```
select
  u.user_id,
  min(u.registration_date) as registration_date,
  count(t.user_id) as transactions
from user u
left join transaction t on t.user_id = u.user_id
  and t.tx_date between u.registration_date
                    and dateadd(day, 60, u.registration_date) 
group by u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have two tables, which I will call `users` and `transactions`:

```
select u.user_id, u.registration_date, count(t.user_id)
from users u left join
     transactions t
     on t.user_id = u.user_id and
        t.transaction_date >= u.registration_date and
        t.transaction_date < dateadd(day, 60, u.registration_date)
group by u.user_id, u.registration_date;
```